# mysql_insert_id() not returning a value -

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-insert-id

I need to retrieve the auto increment field from my database table. I tried the following but `$id` is always just empty.

The insert works too.

My table is as follows:
id`int(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,`

and `id` is set as primary

What am I doing wrong?
        $conn = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
        mysql_select_db($database, $conn) or die( "Unable to select database");
        include "update_activity.php";
        updateActivity("logged in", "On Break");

```
    $date = date("m/d/y"); $starttime = time();
    $sesh = $_SESSION['fname']." ".$_SESSION['lname'];
    $q = "INSERT INTO `breaks` (date, starttime, user) VALUES ('".$date."', '".$starttime."', '".$sesh."')";

    $query = mysql_query($q, $conn);
    $id = mysql_insert_id($conn);

    echo var_dump($id); exit;
```

edited to show my more recent attempts

Comment: at least `PDO`, look at the red box http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: oh my goodness.. i know all about the mysqli thank you for the billionth reminder

Comment: anyone got an answer btw?

Comment: Please, specify resource for `mysql_query` and `mysql_insert_id` functions

Comment: Print out the SQL you're generating, and run it directly in the database - does it work then?

Comment: @adelphia as far as i get the idea there is either a problem in the query that is executed or either because the function is decrepited.

Comment: why? it's not required. the entire script is like 10 lines long. why bother with optional fields if it won't fix the problem.

Comment: @andrewski yes I did that. the query itself is fine.

Comment: @Adelphia try `var_dump($id)`, is it `0` or `false`?

Comment: @Uby it returns false

Comment: What does `mysql_query` return, and what do your logs say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have read all comments given and your replies to each.
Only one of these is possible:

1. Either the query works properly OR
2. You are not getting the generated primary key.

Both of these can never be true.

Define, how you know query is working? Do you know the max PK before and after the running query? Is the insert happening from some other place or thread or even other user? the query is working properly from code or from your mysql client?

To diagnose the problem, we have to go though the normal way.

1. Dump your generated query before calling `mysql_query`.
2. Wrap a error checking system around your query call so php can tell you if the query worked or not. I am sure just by these two steps you will realize the root cause of the problem.

   ```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors','on');

   echo "before calling: $q\n";
   $query = mysql_query($q, $conn);
   if(!$query)
   {
       echo "Error:" . mysql_error($conn);
       return;
   }
   echo " generated id:" . mysql_insert_id($conn);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

@adelphia as far as i get the idea there is a problem in the query that is executed.
plz check the query properly

Comment: the query is fine. it's inserting into the table.

Comment: i mean is there some other way i could improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Borrow a lead from this code extracted from here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your insert query

```
$q = "INSERT INTO `breaks` (date, starttime, user) 
      VALUES ('".$date."', 
              '".$starttime."',
              '".$_SESSION['fname'] $_SESSION['lname']."')";
```

try with this

and main thing you are using most of the deprecated "mysql" things like "mysql_insert_id()"

Answer (score 0):

store the values that u want to pass into an array or variable and pass it in the insert query.
its should work fine then...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation).